# Lambda function to call member function that has access to class members

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Asked this before but didn't get an answer. Cleaned up the example code and removed any Qt. Now what I want to achieve is a function that gets called with a command string and branches to the appropriate function, instead of having something like

```
if ( str == "Task1" ) task1();  // QString if anyone wonders about the == :)
else if( str == "Task2" ) ) task2();
// and so on
```

I want to put the call functions in a has and call them with a simple hash lookup. It works as it is calling the function but it seems it doesn't have member access. The below code prints out

> task1: 0
>
> task2: 0

So is that the expected behavior?

If yes, how can I get it to work?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct MyClass
{
    MyClass() {
        m_functions.insert( pair<string, function<void()> >( string( "Task1" ), function<void()>( [this]() { task1(); } ) ) );
        m_functions.insert( pair<string, function<void()> >( string( "Task2" ), function<void()>( [this]() { task2(); } ) ) );
    }

    map<string, function<void()> >m_functions;
    int m_memberValue = 0;

    void callFunc( string key )
    {
        m_memberValue = 42;
        auto func = m_functions.find( key );
        if ( func != m_functions.end() )
        {
            func->second();
        }
    }

    void task1()
    {
        cout << "task1: " << m_memberValue << endl;
    }

    void task2()
    {
        cout << "task2: "  << m_memberValue << endl;
    }

};


int main()
{
    MyClass object1;
    MyClass object2;
    vector<MyClass>objects;
    objects.push_back( object1 );
    objects.push_back( object2 );

    objects[0].callFunc( string( "Task1" ) );
    objects[1].callFunc( string( "Task2" ) );
    string str;
    getline( cin, str );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: m_functions and m_memberValue are global variables, not members. http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/82-classes-and-class-members/

Comment: @GiulioFranco Where did you get that from? They're member variables. The indentation probably tripped you up.

Comment: Code pasting in SO is a pain. Should be clearer now. And seriosly cpp tutorial?

Comment: @Rakete1111 you're right

Comment: @Roest I've seen questions from people with any kind of preparation. Since I thought they were statics, I thought you had misunderstood something about the syntax, and gave you the tutorial so that you could clarify. Don't get offended by that. Even if you were a newbie, my intention was not to offend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialize `object1` and `object2`, `m_functions` contains lambdas that contain a reference to `this`. Everything ok until now. But then when you push the objects into the `std::vector`, `m_functions` also gets copied, along with the reference to the original objects!

When you call `callFunc` on each the vector element, the `m_memberValue` of the vector elements is updated, but then `task1` (and `task2`) from the original objects, `object1` and `object2`, are called. Because you never called `callFunc` on `object1` or `object2`, `m_memberValue` is `0`.

Comment: Ah thanks. Quickly checked it out. It is working with creating the objects with new and pushing the pointer to the vector

Comment: @Roest That's a bad idea. You should create the elements directly into the vector using `emplace_back`, without any pointers and manual memory allocation.

Comment: Ok understandable but here is some fun new bug.
task1: -572662307
task2: 42
when constructing the vector this way
vector<MyClass>objects;
 objects.emplace_back();
 objects.emplace_back();

 objects[0].callFunc( string( "Task1" ) );
 objects[1].callFunc( string( "Task2" ) );

Comment: @Roest That's weird, it works for me and should. I don't see anything wrong with it...

Comment: it seems anything that reorganizes the vector messes up the references as well, if I do it with 5 objects, the first 4 are messed up and the 5th is ok, if I do a reserve( 5 ) before, all 5 are ok

Comment: @Roest Yes, you're absolutely right! The objects get another address, and so that's undefined behavior trying to call the lambda :)

Comment: Too bad that kills that approach entirely.

Comment: @Roest I found it weird that you used a `std::function`. Why don't you use a function pointer, and call that? Then you'll have no problems with reallocations :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145067/discussion-between-roest-and-rakete1111).